# SpicIE Hostinstance null

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, nullreferenceexception

I've been working on an IE9 plugin using the .net4 version of SpicIE. On my development machine, everything works great. While testing on a deployment machine, I keep getting a NullReferenceException when attempting HostInstance.BrowserRef.Navigate(URL). I added some logging and it is being reported as null on both machines, but it works without issue on the dev machine. I know at one time it worked on the deployment one and have no idea what might have broken it.

Relevant code follows:

From the plugin base:

```
public class KB_Toolbar : SpicIE.Host
{
    ...
    public static KB_Toolbar HostInstance;

    public KB_Toolbar() : base()
    {
        HostInstance = this;
    }

    public static void OpenURL(string URL)
    {
        if (HostInstance != null)
            HostInstance.BrowserRef.Navigate(URL);
    }
 }
```

From the toolbar class:

```
    private void MenuClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var URL = vURL[(int)((ToolStripDropDownItem)sender).Tag];
        KB_Toolbar.OpenURL(URL);
    }
```

If I leave the HostInstance != null check there, it does not execute the next line on either machine. If I remove it, it executes with no problem on the dev, and throws a NRE on the deployment. I've tried a number of cheap hacks to work around it with no luck. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on here, especially that it DOES work on the dev machine WHILE supposedly being null.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The answer was a missing /codebase switch in the regasm command.